# Emoji in profile avatar

Tags: android, emoji

I'm in need to setting profile name as profile picture, For this i'll take the first character of word

```
String getImageText(String name) {
        StringBuilder avatarText = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                String[] words = name.split("\\s");//splits the string based on whitespace
                for (int count = 0; (count <= 1 && count < words.length); count++) { // taking first letter of first two words
                    avatarText.append(words[count].charAt(0)); // appending first letter of the string
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while getting image text : " + exception.getMessage(), exception);
        }
        return avatarText.toString();
    }
```

This works pretty good when text contains only words/numbers/special characters.But while setting the emoji as profile name it is not working good.

It displayed like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyd9G.png)

Comment: What text format do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove all emojis:

**Your edited code:**

```java
String removeEmoji(text){
    String regex = "[^\\p{L}\\p{N}\\p{P}\\p{Z}]";
    String result = text.replaceAll(regex, "");
    return result;
}

String getImageText(String inputName) {
        StringBuilder avatarText = new StringBuilder();
        String name = "";
        try {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(inputName)) {
                name = removeEmoji(inputName);
                String[] words = name.split("\\s");//splits the string based on whitespace
                for (int count = 0; (count <= 1 && count < words.length); count++) { // taking first letter of first two words
                    avatarText.append(words[count].charAt(0)); // appending first letter of the string
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while getting image text : " + exception.getMessage(), exception);
        }
        return avatarText.toString();
    }
```

Checkout [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-remove-emojis) for more information